# Integral of multiple gaussians

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

I have the following integration problem,

$F = \int_a^b \int_a^b \mathcal{N}(x;y,\sigma_0)\mathcal{N}(x;0,\sigma_1)\mathcal{N}(y;0,\sigma_1)  dx dy $,

where $\mathcal{N}(x;y,\sigma_0)$ is a gaussian distibution over $x$ with mean $y$ and std. $\sigma_0$.

I want to find $F$ after integration has been performed. Assume $a,b,\sigma_0,\sigma_1$ are all constants. I have tried a few tactics (replacing normals with their taylor series, solving the first integral and converting the ERF to a taylor series, approximating gaussian function by functions of $tanh$) but I keep getting stuck.

Any help or the solution would be greatly appreciated! If there is no obvious way to solve this a good approximation may suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N(x,y, \sigma_0) = \frac{e^{- \frac{(x-y)^2}{2 \sigma_0^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma_0^2}} = \frac{e^{- \frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{2 \sigma_0^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma_0^2}}$

$N(x,0, \sigma_1) N(x,y, \sigma_0) N(y,0, \sigma_2) = \frac{e^{- \frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{2 \sigma_0^2} - \frac{x^2}{2 \sigma_1^2} - \frac{y^2}{2 \sigma_2^2}}}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^3 \sigma_0^2 \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2}}$.

Now you can put $x,y$ into quadratic Terms like $(x-a)^2,(y-b)^2)$ and evaluate the Gaussian integrals separately.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. I think I am missing you last step though - how are you getting around the 2xy doesn't that keep the two variables together?

Comment: After simplifying the Exponent you will have a quadratic function like this: $Q:=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$. For the constants $A,B,C$ you will have $A(x-By)^2+Cy^2=Ax^2-2ABxy+(AB^2+C)y^2=ax^2+bxy+cy^2=Q$. Now you can determine $A,B,C$ from $a,b,c$ and finally you can compute the Gaussian integrals.

Comment: ...more or less, since the domain of integration won't be a rectangle after the diagonalization of the quadratic form.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio could you elaborate? by doing this I seem to still be stuck with one nasty integral so I am not sure how it solves the problem, however I could be simply misunderstanding something

Comment: ah I get what you, essentially rotate the bivariate gaussian such that we simply get the product of error functions, that might be a good approximation alright!